# AWS using single Lambda Function possible to call multiple API's

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

'Put the code for processing all endpoints into one big Lambda function, and pass in the parameter that will tell Lambda function which process it needs to do'

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify more on what you have tried and what is the main problem you are having; still as vague as your question is, maybe you are looking for something like [Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice)

Here is a part from an example in Chalice's README where the same lambda has different functions for different routes

```
from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='helloworld')

CITIES_TO_STATE = {
    'seattle': 'WA',
    'portland': 'OR',
}


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'hello': 'world'}

@app.route('/cities/{city}')
def state_of_city(city):
    return {'state': CITIES_TO_STATE[city]}
```

Comment: hi Edwin , my question is, by using  one lambda function  do CRUD operations and call endpoint url for all functions using  parameters, is it possible?? because for each crud operation have to create one lambda function, its possible to write crud operation in lambda and call endpoint url with parameters

Comment: Yes it is possible, you could give it a try either to https://github.com/aws/chalice for python or https://claudiajs.com/claudia-api-builder.html for nodejs, just to name a few. Those tools help configuring API Gateway and setting up a Lambda that processes the different routes so you could have the whole CRUD there

Comment: Hi Edwin Please check my below post